# Using string.compare in a linq query where clause

Tags: linq

I am having a bit of trouble figuring out the exact syntax to use string.compare in the Where clause of a linq query.  Below is what I have so far.

```
filteredApplications = AllApplications.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(string.Compare(x.Name, txtSearch.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))).ToList();
```

Is this even possible or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Rhonda

Comment: `String.Compare()` returns an int.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are using `Contains` and `Compare`...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to check to see if `Name` contains the search text:

```
AllApplications.Where(x => x.Name.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(txtSearch.Text.ToUpperInvariant()))).ToList();
```

If you want to check for equality:

```
AllApplications.Where(x => string.Equals(x.Name, txtSearch.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

In your original query, you were checking to see if `x.Name` contains the result of `string.Compare`. I assume you weren't trying to do this, since [`string.Compare` returns an integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare.aspx). `string.Compare` is used primarily for determining sort order.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for `Equals` if you're looking to match by equality:

```
filteredApplications = AllApplications.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(txtSearch.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```